# How should I pass argument in function in my case?

Tags: go

There is a function that requests a token. I have a problem when I call it again to try to get the token again. In the body I see the following:
`{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing form parameter: grant_type"}`

I figured out that the problem lies in passing the payload argument. If I don't pass it, but just copy it inside function, everything is ok. Apparently, it has to be passed in some other way than `payload *strings.Reader` What's the reason for this behavior of the function and how to correctly pass payload argument into it? I need to pass it, not copy it inside because of reusing this function in my code.

`fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(payload)) >> *strings.Reader`

```
func getTokenAgain(payload *strings.Reader) string {
    //payload := strings.NewReader("grant_type=password&username=admin&password=secret&client_id=admin-cli")
    url := "https://my-api-url.com/auth/realms/CP/protocol/openid-connect/token"
    method := "POST"
    client := &http.Client{} 
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)      
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    accessToken := gjson.Get(string(body), "access_token")
    return accessToken.String()
}
```

Comment: If you want to re-read the reader's contents then you need to move the reader's "cursor" back to the position where the data that you're trying to read starts. It definitely won't move itself there. https://pkg.go.dev/strings@go1.17.5#Reader.Seek

Comment: Why don't you just pass the payload argument as a string and then build in the string.Reader in getTokenAgain from that paramater ?